# Kinect sdk version compatibility issue

Tags: c#, kinect-sdk

I am working on Kinect project for Blob detection using Kinect sdk 2.0.

After doing so much efforts to find reference tutorial for it, I found out following tutorial.

http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2012/11/blob-tracking-kinect-opencv-wpf/

The issue is that this example is built on Kinect sdk 1.8 . Because of that, some events and methods which are not supported in kinect sdk 2.0.

for eg.
private void sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, ***AllFramesReadyEventArgs*** e)

(Error:***The type or namespace name AllFramesReadyEventArgs could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembley reference?***))

I tried to find out those events and methods new name for kinect sdk 2.0 but I didn't get anything.

Comment: A program named Kinect SDK Browser has been installed along with your kinect sdk. You'll find lot of examples in the SDK browser and the examples covers about everything you can do with kinect v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different frame callback that listens to `MultiSourceFrameReader`. This can receive `BodyFrameType`, `DepthFrameType`, `ColorFrameType`, etc. simultaneously.

For example:

```
private void Reader_FrameArrived(object sender, MultiSourceFrameArrivedEventArgs e) {

    using (BodyFrame bodyFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame().BodyFrameReference.AcquireFrame()) {
        // do something
    }

    using (DepthFrame depthFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame().DepthFrameReference.AcquireFrame()) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

To add a frame to this callback, instantiate a `MultiSourceFrameReader reader` object and do this:

```
this.reader.MultiSourceFrameArrived += Reader_FrameArrived;
```